# Azure Custom Role for Operators and Developers

Tags: azure-security, azure-rbac

We are currently review our user access permission for Azure.  We want to review and further refine the existing/built-in roles that came with Azure.  For example, the Contributor access may be a bit too much in some instance.  Specifically, below are two roles ware are trying to create:

- DEVELOPER:  Currently our Developers are assigned Contributor by default.  The issue here is that this gives them the ability the create/delete resources as will.  Resources are typically pre-created by the Cloud Team.  We want to limit that.  Ideally, we want to give them the ability to configure resources and start/stop rescues.
- OPERATOR:  This is for our IT folks who need to review resources and start and restart resources.  Similar to the Developer roles above, they don't need to create/delete resources.

Any suggestions or roles examples that can help achieve the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure Custom Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles). Take a look at the [Azure Portal Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal) and the [Azure resource provider operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations).